# Any solution to error: resource android:attr/popupPromptView is private?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have an android project that was made in eclipse, I have imported it to Android Studio started fixing the errors, but I don't know how to fix this one

I have already changed the `targetSdkVersion`, `minSdkVersion` and `compileVersion`, I also changed some dependencies but still not a fix

Here is my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.wansoft"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 28
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
    'proguard-rules.txt'
            }
        }

        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
    implementation project(':sherlockSlidingMenu')
    implementation project(':pullToRefresh')
    implementation project(':roboAccordionView')
    //compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    implementation 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    //compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    implementation files('libs/commons-lang3-3.1.jar')
    implementation files('libs/guice-3.0-no_aop.jar')
    implementation files('libs/http-request-5.4.jar')
    implementation files('libs/jackson-core-asl-1.9.11.jar')
    implementation files('libs/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.11.jar')
    implementation files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
    implementation files('libs/retrofit-1.6.1.jar')
    implementation files('libs/roboguice-2.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/spring-android-core-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar')
    implementation files('libs/spring-android-rest-template-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:+'
   }
```

and here is the error i get:

```
Android resource linking failed
/Users/dario_leija/Documents/Proyectos_Documentos/ComanderoAndroid/wansoftApp/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:1550: error: resource android:attr/popupPromptView is private.
error: failed linking references.
```

Comment: So, nobody can help me? anyone that had this error in the past?